# What's the difference between Public variable and Public Property in VB.NET? (Code Analysis VS2010, CA1051 : Microsoft.Design)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

When running code analysis on my project, I receive the following message:

`CA1051 : Microsoft.Design : Because field 'ClassName.VarName' is visible outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility to private and add a property, with the same accessibility as the field has currently, to provide access to it.`

To resolve this, I can change the following line:

```
Public VarName As String
```

to this:

```
Public Property VarName As String
```

I don't understand why the `Property` keyword is so important in this particular case.  Can anyone provide an explanation as to why changing this member to a `Property` makes a significant difference to code analysis?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Public Property VarName As String` declares a property providing a level of encapsulation. You will be able to access the private member state of this variable within your class by using _VarName.

`Public VarName As String` declares a variable that will just provide a single public instance of this variable and no encapsulation.

Comment: So, using encapsulation is considered a best practice in .NET?

Comment: I'd say so if you wanted to implement access control (probably not in your case - maybe in future?), or to hide implementation from calling code.

Comment: It is 99.9% doubtful that I will ever have to touch this code again, but I do agree hat encapsulation is important for the maintainability of code.

Answer (score 3):

Using 'Property' allows you to define public access methods for your variables instead of making those variables public. See here for a good explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It has always been good coding practice to make your variables private and provide public properties to access the data.

For example, if you later need to add some event that gets raised when the value changes, it's a lot easier to stick that code in the set property and all existing code that uses the property doesn't need to be touched but if you keep using the variable and then decide you need to raise an event you would have to create a property that sets the value and raises the event and then update all existing code to use the new property you just created instead of the variable.

Comment: Always since VB.Net, anyway. In VB6 you could replace a public variable with a property without needing to touch the callers. It's about the only thing that was better in VB6 than .Net.

Comment: Even in VB6 it's good to use properties the first time. Letting you do something you shouldn't do in the first place is not necessarily "better".

Comment: Why do you think it's "something you shouldn't do in the first place" (in VB6)? I mean, +1 good answer for VB.Net, but it doesn't apply for VB6. In VB6 "if you keep using the variable and then decide you need to raise an event you would have to create a property that sets the value and raises the event and then *you don't need to touch* any existing code, it automatically uses the property".

Comment: I'm saying just because VB6 allows you to do that, it's not a good reason to not use properties in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you've said that twice now.  And I'm asking why, twice how. **What is the benefit of using properties in the first place?** VB6 public variables are equivalent to VB 2010 automatically implemented properties.

Comment: It's just like anything in life, just because you're allowed to do something doesn't mean you should. At the very least just to build good habits because when you do move out of vb6 land bad habits can carry over. And what happens if Microsoft updates vb6 to not work that way any more? (99.99% joking on that last bit. That'll never happen).

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulation is an important principle in OOD. If you expose your members to others (I know, I'm already giggling myself), there's no guarantee you'll be able to maintain proper state.

By using properties, you can protect your members' state by defining clear guidelines on how the members are accessed.

Comment: True, true.  I am writing something so simple, that any get/set is just default.  In the past when I needed to encapsulate something I would just rewrite with a getter/setter... but I never would do that will ALL my public members... I guess best practice is that you should for all?

Comment: @afuzzyllama: Yeah, it doesn't hurt to do it for all members... specially since VB.NET probably has auto-properties, just like C#.

Comment: VB.NET has auto implemented properties in 2010. Previous versions do not.